# npm start fails, angular2 quickstart

Tags: node.js, npm-install

How can i fix this issue?

I am giving my best to solve this issue but problem still exists. 
I am using node.js v7.6.0.

I appriciate every help!

```html
$ npm start
...........
.........

npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to in                                                                                                                stall?

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gerrix\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-02-22T21_50_33                                                                                                                _132Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you run npm install like it says?

Comment: Omg, I am stupid as hell.. I never let installation to finish process and its reason why every time I got this kind of error.